# sharing canon all in one over network

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, scanner, sane

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on an old computer I want to use as a file and printer server in a small office. I have samba sharing set up for file sharing and I've been able to get all the computers to print via CUPS. I am now trying to get the scanner to work.

On the Ubuntu server I can scan an image using Simple Scan or xsane. I used [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/sane.d%20tutorial) 
to set up saned and I can confirm that the saned process is running. I then downloaded and installed the TWAIN SANE Interface for MacOS X binaries from http://www.ellert.se/twain-sane/

I added the ip address of the ubuntu server to /usr/local/etc/sane.d/net.conf but when I open image capture on my mac I don't see any devices.

I run `scanimage -L` on the Ubuntu machine and I get

```
device `pixma:04A91737_32E09E' is a CANON Canon PIXMA MX330 multi-function peripheral
device `net:127.0.0.1:pixma:04A91737' is a CANON Canon PIXMA MX330 multi-function peripheral
device `net:localhost:pixma:04A91737' is a CANON Canon PIXMA MX330 multi-function peripheral
```

when I use xsane the pixma:04A91737_32E09E device scans properly the other two give me the error `Failed to open device 'net:127.0.0.1:pixma:04A91737`:Access to resource has been denied.

I think this has something to do with configuring the [sane pixma backend](http://www.sane-project.org/man/sane-pixma.5.html) but I'm confused about the BJNP proticol.

Can anyone help me out with getting the scanner to work over the network?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I found that the comment from Lee in [this link](http://mp610.blogspot.com/2008/04/give-your-scanner-new-freshly-sane.html?showComment=1230663420000) helps.  The file referred to by Lee can be found as /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules in Precise Pangolin

Comment: Hi! Whilst this may help the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. But in this specific case, it's possible that things may have changed since Lee's comment so you could edit your answer to point out that the link relates to Ubuntu 8.04 and that's why you have not provided material from there.